# How can I remove NA's from a large data frame but keeping the structure of separated columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data frame that looks like this :

```
date = c(rep(as.Date("2022/1/1"),3),
         rep(as.Date("2022/1/2"),3),
         rep(as.Date("2022/1/3"),3))
var1 = c(rep("cat",3),rep("cat,Mother,bike,pasta",3),rep("dog,bird",3))
a = seq(1,9,1)
b = seq(10,18,1)
c = seq(19,27,1)
df = tibble(date,a,b,c,var1);df

# A tibble: 9 × 5
  date           a     b     c var1                 
  <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr>                
1 2022-01-01     1    10    19 cat                  
2 2022-01-01     2    11    20 cat                  
3 2022-01-01     3    12    21 cat                  
4 2022-01-02     4    13    22 cat,Mother,bike,pasta
5 2022-01-02     5    14    23 cat,Mother,bike,pasta
6 2022-01-02     6    15    24 cat,Mother,bike,pasta
7 2022-01-03     7    16    25 dog,bird             
8 2022-01-03     8    17    26 dog,bird             
9 2022-01-03     9    18    27 dog,bird
```

I use separate_rows and pivot wider to separate the character vector into columns :

```
df%>%separate_rows(var1)%>%
  group_by(date) %>% 
  mutate(id = row_number())%>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = id, values_from = var1)
```

resulting to :

```
# A tibble: 9 × 16
# Groups:   date [3]
  date           a     b     c `1`   `2`    `3`   `4`   `5`   `6`    `7`   `8`   `9`   `10`   `11`  `12` 
  <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr> <chr>
1 2022-01-01     1    10    19 cat   NA     NA    NA    NA    NA     NA    NA    NA    NA     NA    NA   
2 2022-01-01     2    11    20 NA    cat    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA    NA    NA    NA     NA    NA   
3 2022-01-01     3    12    21 NA    NA     cat   NA    NA    NA     NA    NA    NA    NA     NA    NA   
4 2022-01-02     4    13    22 cat   Mother bike  pasta NA    NA     NA    NA    NA    NA     NA    NA   
5 2022-01-02     5    14    23 NA    NA     NA    NA    cat   Mother bike  pasta NA    NA     NA    NA   
6 2022-01-02     6    15    24 NA    NA     NA    NA    NA    NA     NA    NA    cat   Mother bike  pasta
7 2022-01-03     7    16    25 dog   bird   NA    NA    NA    NA     NA    NA    NA    NA     NA    NA   
8 2022-01-03     8    17    26 NA    NA     dog   bird  NA    NA     NA    NA    NA    NA     NA    NA   
9 2022-01-03     9    18    27 NA    NA     NA    NA    dog   bird   NA    NA    NA    NA     NA    NA
```

but my desire data frame must be like this :

| date | a | b | c | `1` | `2` | `3` | `4` |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-01-01 | 1 | 10 | 19 | cat | NA | NA | NA |
| 2022-01-01 | 2 | 11 | 20 | cat | NA | NA | NA |
| 2022-01-01 | 3 | 12 | 21 | cat | NA | NA | NA |
| 2022-01-02 | 4 | 13 | 22 | cat | Mother | bike | pasta |
| 2022-01-02 | 5 | 14 | 23 | cat | Mother | bike | pasta |
| 2022-01-02 | 6 | 15 | 24 | cat | Mother | bike | pasta |
| 2022-01-03 | 7 | 16 | 25 | dog | bird | NA | NA |
| 2022-01-03 | 8 | 17 | 26 | dog | bird | NA | NA |
| 2022-01-03 | 9 | 18 | 27 | dog | bird | NA | NA |

how can I do this in R ?
Any help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may split the 'var1' and use `unnest_wider`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(var1 = strsplit(var1, ",")) %>%
  unnest_wider(var1, names_sep = "")
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 9 × 8
  date           a     b     c var11 var12  var13 var14
  <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr>  <chr> <chr>
1 2022-01-01     1    10    19 cat   <NA>   <NA>  <NA> 
2 2022-01-01     2    11    20 cat   <NA>   <NA>  <NA> 
3 2022-01-01     3    12    21 cat   <NA>   <NA>  <NA> 
4 2022-01-02     4    13    22 cat   Mother bike  pasta
5 2022-01-02     5    14    23 cat   Mother bike  pasta
6 2022-01-02     6    15    24 cat   Mother bike  pasta
7 2022-01-03     7    16    25 dog   bird   <NA>  <NA> 
8 2022-01-03     8    17    26 dog   bird   <NA>  <NA> 
9 2022-01-03     9    18    27 dog   bird   <NA>  <NA>
```

---

or with `separate`

```
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
colnms <- as.character(seq_len(max(str_count(df$var1, ",")+1)))
separate(df, var1, into = colnms, sep = ",", fill = "right")
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 9 × 8
  date           a     b     c `1`   `2`    `3`   `4`  
  <date>     <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr>  <chr> <chr>
1 2022-01-01     1    10    19 cat   <NA>   <NA>  <NA> 
2 2022-01-01     2    11    20 cat   <NA>   <NA>  <NA> 
3 2022-01-01     3    12    21 cat   <NA>   <NA>  <NA> 
4 2022-01-02     4    13    22 cat   Mother bike  pasta
5 2022-01-02     5    14    23 cat   Mother bike  pasta
6 2022-01-02     6    15    24 cat   Mother bike  pasta
7 2022-01-03     7    16    25 dog   bird   <NA>  <NA> 
8 2022-01-03     8    17    26 dog   bird   <NA>  <NA> 
9 2022-01-03     9    18    27 dog   bird   <NA>  <NA>
```

Comment: if the number of columns is not countable (humanly) someone would prefer the first solution.How about the second solution ? For example the number of columns might be 245.the`into = as.character(1:4)` becomes difficult.

Comment: @HomerJaySimpson one option is to get the max count of delimiter and use that for passing the column name as in the update